# Selenium Junit-Initialization error

Tags: selenium, junit

Below is the code-I am getting intialization error while running the below code
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collection;

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;




@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class test1 {

public String name;
public int acc;

public test1(String name,int acc)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.acc=acc;

}

@Test
public void bank()
{
    System.out.println(name+acc);
}




@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getdata()
{
    Object data[][]= new Object[1][2];
    data[1][0]="ddd";
    data[1][1]=123;
    return Arrays.asList(data);

}
}
```

I am getting Intialization error while running this code.

Comment: I ran this code. I am not seeing any error. Can you post the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The initialization error is caused by a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

In the `getData` method the variable `data` is accessed with index 1 for the first dimension but the index of arrays start at zero. Change the method to

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getdata() {
    Object data[][] = new Object[1][2];
    data[0][0] = "ddd";
    data[0][1] = 123;
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}
```